# Spring saml: why in saml response, key info could be encrypted?

Tags: xml, encryption, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

From my understanding, if idp wants to encrypt saml response assertions. Idp would encrypt it using the encryption public key provided by SP, and SP will use the private key to decrypt it.

But this is part of the SAML response I get from an idp

```
<EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
   <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
               <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            </e:EncryptionMethod>
            <KeyInfo>
               <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                  <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                     <ds:X509IssuerName>...</ds:X509IssuerName>
                     <ds:X509SerialNumber>1142467415</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                  </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
               </ds:X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
            <e:CipherData>
               <e:CipherValue>...</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
         </e:EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <xenc:CipherData>...</xenc:CipherData>
   </xenc:EncryptedData>
</EncryptedAssertion>
```

After going through source code, SP's encryption public key, instead of used to en/decrypt assertion, is used to en/decrypt another key, and that key is used to  en/decrypt assertion (so 2 keypairs are involved instead of just 1).

I look at source code of org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.

If field resolver is set, decryptUsingResolvedKey() will be used. This is what I think should Always be used.

If field encKeyResolver is set, decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey() will be used.

There are 2 things that confuse me:

1. in spring saml extension, when populateDecrypter(), resolver is set to null. Why is that?
2. what is the purpose of decrypt Using Resolved Encrypted Key? Why involve 2 pairs of key instead of just using 1?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know why, the reason 2 keys are involved is to increase speed.

the public/private key (RSA etc) is used to en/decrypt a AES key, and the AES key is used to en/decrypt the actual message.

Since AES is much faster than RSA, and AES is much shorter than the actual message. Doing this will be faster than just use RSA key to en/decrypt the actual message.

Security is still protected since you need the AES key to read message and you need the RSA key to read the AES key.

Comment: Which is called [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) and is nearly universal.